# How to get Block children in Magento?

Tags: magento

I am inside a **phtml** file, how can I get the list of children blocks within the current template?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
$children = $this->getChild();
```

Check the code within **app/code/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php**

```
public function getChild($name = '')
{
    if ($name === '') {
        return $this->_children;
    } elseif (isset($this->_children[$name])) {
        return $this->_children[$name];
    }
    return false;
}
```

So if no name is given, it simply returns all children.

Comment: can we also use $this->getChildHtml()  ? with block name in it?

Comment: @RIK: `$this->getChildHtml()` will return all the html content of all child blocks.

Comment: @skafandri: in my layout xml file I'd added a child `cms/block`. then im my parent *phtml* file I'd written `$_block = $this->getChild('block_id');` then `$_block->getTitle()` then it doesn't show the title... neither `$_block->getContent()` return html content. if i try `print_r($_block)` the page script die. How can I get the title of my cms block in phtml?